# How to create link without PGID

Tags: intershop

How to create a link without a PGID at ISML level?

The following code is great for avoiding the session id in an url but still adds the PGID at the end of the url.

```
#sessionlessurl(Action(TargetPipeline))#
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you cannot do that with `sessionlessurl` and I also think that there is no ISML function that can do it. But there is a custom tag that is used for the generation of canonical links and you may also make use of it. The tag is called `issetcanonicallink`. Here is code example:

```
<issetcanonicallink 
    scope="request"
    name="CanonicalLink"
    action="ViewStandardCatalog-Browse" 
    parameters="#ParameterList(Parameter('CatalogID', CategoryBO:CatalogBO:Name), Parameter('CategoryName', CategoryBO:Name))#">

<link rel="canonical" href="<isprint encoding="off" value="#CanonicalLink#">" />
```

The implementation `SetCanonicalLinkTag` is located in the `core` cartridge and the parameters are documented accordingly.

Comment: Actually funny since I already modified this tag in our project ;-) Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 0):

My current solution to create a url without sid and pgid is this:

```
<%
    String targetPipeline = getPipelineDictionary().get("targetPipeline");
    URLPipelineAction action = new URLPipelineAction(targetPipeline);
    action.setAppendPGID(false);



    // Default Link
    String myDefaultLink = TemplateURLComposition.getTemplateExecutionConfig().getURLComposer().createURL(false, null, null, null, action, null);
    getPipelineDictionary().put("myDefaultLink", myDefaultLink);

%>

<isprint value="#myDefaultLink#">
```

Feel free to add a better one which uses less JSP:)
URLParameters are missing but you can easily add them as well within the JSP part.